# blank value in select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a blank value in select which, when i input into the database in an array (serialized) - will include this blank value together with the array - which i do not want.

I need this blank value to be off but the select view having to have a "no selection" option.

```
   <%= f.select(:newpages, @pages, { :default => nil } , :include_blank => false, :multiple => true, :size => '7', :selected => @selected ) %>
```

I have tried having :include_blank => false within {} and the above is without.

Thanks!

Edit:

The output shows as this:

["", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

The first "" is always included which i do not know why, even after setting :include_blank => false

Comment: Maybe there is a page in your `@pages` that is empty?

Comment: @pages is an array of numbers that is displayed - does not have any empty number in the array.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <%= f.select(:newpages, @pages, { :include_blank => true } %>
```

It should show you an empty option in select view. Empty value that you are telling about, should be coming from your collection '@pages'. Please verify the collection once about, if that has any empty values.

Comment: Can i remove the empty "value" from being saved into the database?

It is because when i selected the empty option, the values goes out as:  ["", ""] in an array.

Comment: More info when clicking on button to update:

 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BD6Ma7/5cIP6kp5+4ja7LPJnKDlIfmX/7B6/vPHPazY=", "print"=>{"quantity"=>"1", "newpages"=>["", ""], "comment"=>"No comment."}, "commit"=>"Update Print", "id"=>"3"}

Comment: You might be adding 'multiple:true' option, Otherwise it wont take that in array. That need to be removed and make sure "@pages" collection does not have any spaces